# How can I get .length in Type input

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int num = s.nextInt(); 
    int a = num.length; //This part
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

If I enter **4321**, I want to get length of entered length. I already try to input Integer variable "a" but it did't right. T.T

(Example: length : 4) when I use `int a = num.length;`, it did't get num's length as well as Strings When I want get `"Hello".length();`

It seem like did't exist. I want to get length but I don't know how.

Is there other way to get `.length`?

Comment: convert the number to a string and then get the length of the string

Comment: What is the length of an integer?

Comment: you can do something like `%10` and then `/10` in a loop and count the iterations needed until you have no more result in the divison

Comment: Thanks everybody it is helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   int num = s.nextInt();
   int length = String.valueOf(num).length();
   System.out.println(length);}
```

if you want to get lenth of string then use bellow code

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = number.nextLine();
System.out.println(a.length());
```

Comment: Thanks you How can i adopt this Comment? i'm noob. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you cast your `int` to `String` you then you can get its length for example :

```
int a = num.length;
String s = a + "";
int lng = s.length();
```

Comment: no @AndyTurner `s = a + "";` i makes a mistake check now

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do it this way;

```
int length =  String.valueOf(num).length();
```

or

```
int length = Integer.toString(num).length();
```

The obove mentioned solution with the + Operator works aswell but is considered to be rather dirty;

Answer (score 0):

If you read the input as a String, you can obtain its length :

```
String num = s.next();
int a = num.length();
```